# GCC: Linking objects with colliding variable names

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

Working with c++, gcc.
I have several build variants with different constants and variable values. The idea is to generate an unified binary covering all those variants.

What I would like to achieve:

- Compile variant 1 and generate the objects.
- Compile variant 2 and generate the objects.

**Option 1:** Linker to detect automatically the colliding variable names and rename them ONLY if they contain different values, allowing to link all objects together. If the variables have the same name and value then do not duplicate it.

- Is this possible? Are there any linker options allowing this?

**Option 2:** Postprocess those objects and rename the colliding variables that have different values. Link all postprocessed objects together generating a single binary.

- Is there any solution available following this idea?

Any other ideas how this could be done?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Sounds like you want a clairvoyant linker which knows what you want, not what you command. This is an XY problem. Your approach is wrong from the beginning. In a library, functions with identical name shall behave identical. Same for global variables (which should not be used anyway).

Comment: An example use-case would be appropriate.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at your design again, in particular which items are public or global.   Functions not in a class can be `static` to the compilation unit, and should be unless they are designed to be shared.